# Weird behaviour of string variables in bash script...Please help!

Tags: bash, string

I'm going nuts with this...let me explain...

I have a very simple Bash script with a function in it that receives 3 arguments. Those arguments are all strings. Everything was working fine 'til I had to pass a string with whitespaces to the function.

I also have some test code to call the function (whose name is substracFromFile):

```
# try the function

PATTERN=`echo -e '<Location test14>'`

echo "PATTERN IS $PATTERN"

HEADERPATTERN=`echo -e '<Location [a-zA-Z0-9]*>'`

echo "HEADERPATTERN IS $HEADERPATTERN"

FILE="subversion.conf"

echo "FILE IS $FICHERO"

substracFromFile $PATTERN $HEADERPATTERN $FILE
```

The output of this is:

```
PATTERN IS <Location prueba14>
HEADERPATTERN IS <Location [a-zA-Z0-9]*>
FILE IS subversion.conf
PATTERN ARGUMENT IS <Location
HEADERPATTERN ARGUMENT IS prueba14>
FILE ARGUMENT IS <Location
grep: <Location: No such file or directory
expr: syntax error
```

As you can see, when arguments are passed to the function and I echoed them to screen they are somehow splitted in the white space...let me show you the function initial code:

```
function substracFromFile
{

        PATTERN=$1

        HEADERPATTERN=$2

        FILE=$3

        # Debug only
        echo "HEADER ARGUMENT IS $PATTERN"

        # Debug only
        echo "HEADERPATTERN ARGUMENT IS $HEADERPATTERN"

        # Debug only
        echo "FILE ARGUMENT IS $FILE"
```

This was working sweet as long as passed strings had no whitespaces at all. When I call  the function strings seem to be ok, but I don't understand why they are splitted once the function is called....I'm sure this is something pretty dull, but I just don't get it...

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: try adding double quotes to all your variables

Answer (score 1):

Parts of your question are inconsistent with other parts. For example:

```
FILE="subversion.conf"

echo "FILE IS $FICHERO"
```

But I'm assuming those are just errors made while posting the question.

As **ghostdog74** mentioned in a comment, you need to quote variables that contain whitespace. In particular, this line should have quotes around the variables:

```
substracFromFile "$PATTERN" "$HEADERPATTERN" "$FILE"
```

Also, I don't see why you're using `echo` to set variables in lines such as this one:

```
PATTERN=`echo -e '<Location test14>'`
```

This could simply be:

```
PATTERN='<Location test14>'
```

If the value sometimes has escaped special characters in it, you can use one of these methods:

```
PATTERN=$'value\nwith\tescapes'
```

which would have "value" newline "with" tab "escapes" as its value.

Also, I recommend getting in the habit of not using all-caps for variable names. This will reduce the chance of name collisions with Bash's built-in variables.

Comment: Hi Dennis, you're right, those are just typos, I translated the script from spanish to english while I was posting...sorry.

The issue here is when I get the arguments in the function, if they have whitespaces they get messed up. I'll try to call the function with quoted arguments, not sure if I already tried that.

I'll let you know if I make any progress

Agreed about variable names :)

Regards

Comment: You were right, quoting arguments when calling the function solved the issue...I'd like to understand the reason for this though...

Thanks again
Alex

Comment: @AlejandroVK: Quoting arguments prevents them from being split on whitespace (the characters contained in the `IFS` variable - usually space, tab and newline). This is common to most if not all Unix shells. [Further reading](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) and [here](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC35).